# SQL Pivot Table for Many-To-Many Relationship for use in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, pivot-table

Using SQL Server 2008, I am trying to figure out how to create a query that returns a pivot table with a standard many-to-many relationship.  This relationship defines which users belong to which roles and I want the table to list the user name along the side and the role names across the top.  The ultimate goal is to have this output in SQL Server Reporting Services, so it doesn't matter if SQL server generates the pivot results, or SSRS generates the results (is one method better than the other?).  Here is my sample schema:

**Users** Table:

- UserID
- UserName

**Rights** Table:

- RightID
- RightName

**RightsMembership** Table:

- UserID
- RightID

I want the following output as a report in SSRS.  Any help is appreciated.

```
       RightOne   RightTwo   RightThree   RightFour
jdoe       X          X
mjane      X                       X
ssmith                X            X           X
```

FYI: Roles can be added, so I would prefer not to have to hard code the role name or count in the query.

Comment: If this isn't answered by the time I get home in about 3 hours I will start to answer it. Just so you know, the solution I'm thinking of will require a stored procedure that runs dynamic SQL and a matrix in your report.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I found a site that shows something similar to what I want using the "pivot" command in SQL server, but the example he uses doesn't quite match what I'm looking for (a one-to-many relationship).  Any thoughts on this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx?

Comment: PIVOT requires that every column be explicitly named that it is going to create. Because of that you need to create your query dynamically. SELECT DISTINCT RightsName FROM Rights will get you the list of them that you can use to build the query string. Then you use sp_executesql to run your dynamic query. Using a matrix with a column group in SSRS will allow a dynamic count of columns. When I get home I'll clarify all this with more detail in an answer. :)

Comment: Also, would you like the list limited to the permissions the current user can see? As in, you send in a UserId and it gives you a table that has every user and whether or not they have each right that the UserId has access to? Or do you just want to get a list every user compared to every right?

Comment: The list will be for administrative reporting uses, so no, it does not need to be limited.

Comment: As Jeremy observes, pivoting in SQL requires that each column has to be explicitly specified, requiring dynamic SQL where these are not known in advance. Dynamic SQL is a pain in the neck; pivoting in SSRS is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Don't Know about the Pivot Tables but you can achieve this in the SSRS as below

```
Select UserName,
           RightName
From users u INNER JOIN RightMembership rm on rm.UserID = u.UserID
             INNER JOIN Rights r on rm.RightID = r.RightID
```

Use this query as the Stored Procedure or Query and the Order By Accordingly and

Create the Dataset and Datasource

Insert matrix in the report

In the rows select the UserName field From the Created Dataset 
In the columns select the RightName field from the created Dataset
In the Data use this Expression below then you will get the desired output
=IIF(Fields!UserName.Value = nothing,nothing,"X") As the Data in the matrix

Comment: That worked perfectly.  In the report wizard, I wasn't able to create a matrix without any value in the detail area, so I modified the query just slightly to add `1 as Available` as a third field.  Once I did that and used the **Available** field in the detail, the wizard designed the report as needed.  Thanks for your help!